# multiple forms in CreateView

Tags: python, django, forms

I have two forms in my CreateView. Forms will be totally  independent. It means they will be submitted independently. How can I achieve it in class based CreateView without overriding POST method?

```
class EventPage(CreateView):
    template_name = 'event.html'
    form_class = RegisterToEvent

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.event = Event.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['event_id'])
        return super(EventPage, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        event = Event.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['event_id'])
        participants = Participant.objects.filter(event_id = event.id)
        context['participants'] = participants
        context['event'] = event
        context['upload_document_form'] = UploadDocument
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good place to use Django [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/)

> A formset is a layer of abstraction to work with multiple forms on the
>   same page

Another way is to parse submit button names from POST. For example:

```
if 'first_form_submit_name' in request.POST:
    # do some stuff for first form
elif 'second_form_name' in request.POST:
    # do some stuff for second one
```

Comment: But I need totally independent forms. Forms will be submitted independently. As I understand I can't achieve this with formsets. Or I am not right?

Comment: @Added one more solution. please check